# mysqli prepared statement bind param array of ids

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have simple prepared statement, and i can't find solution to bind list of id's, so as you can see in first statement i get all ids that i need, and in next statement i need to put all those ids into IN clause, but i'm not able to do it, any suggestions how and what is best way to do it ?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE groupId = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $args['groupId'], $pageSize, $offset);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);

$userIds= array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $userIds[] = $id;
}

$stmt= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.id as attendantId, a.firstName, a.lastName, c.id as caringId, c.startDate, c.endDate FROM attendant a LEFT JOIN caring c ON c.attendantId = a.id WHERE a.id IN (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userIds);
$stmt->bind_param('i', implode(',', $userIds));
```

Comment: you're using only one placeholder in the second query, and using two bind_param's. That alone should have thrown an error with `mysqli_error($mysqli)` on the query. I think that if you get rid of `$stmt->bind_param('i', $userIds);` it may work.

Comment: Sorry, i added 2 bind params i wanted to say that i tried both ways and none of them works.